# How to use javascript to detect right click when touching image

Tags: javascript, image

I would like to prevent a user by downloading images on my site. I have scrambled my code but they can just right click and press save image. How would I make something like an alert popup when touching and right clicking an image?

Comment: You can't prevent that

Comment: I have seen sights prevent that which is how I know that it is possible

Comment: You can change the right click behavior, but you can't prevent a user from downloading your images. You can only make it a little harder to do. Anything displayed in the browser can be stolen, a way or another (by finding the image's URL in the browser's network tab, by taking a screenshot, etc.)

Comment: CSS: pointer-events: none;